# Looking for a way to append Day of Week to end of line

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, command-line, date

In Ubuntu 16.04, I'm trying to find a way to append the Day of the Week to the end of each line in a text file given the date in field 4.

Sample data:

```
Server ID,Make,"Server Room",Datestamp,Timestamp,Distance,Ping,Download,Upload,Payload,"Src IP Address",Hour,DOW
x6883101,HP,"Server Room A",2019-07-14,04:50:02,26.444,11.521,49193480,41904833,,192.168.1.1,4, 
s3398577,Dell,"Server Room B",2019-09-21,10:50:02,56.574,37.608,48955461,45858381,,192.168.1.1,10, 
x6883551,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-08-16,02:00:04,26.444,17.921,86551957,88775986,,192.168.1.1,2, 
s1555023,HP,"Server Room C",2018-02-06,04:50:01,516.574,402.527,907658,608152,,192.168.1.1,4, 
s3398023,HP,"Server Room B",2019-01-17,10:50:01,56.574,40.233,48484827,45620028,,192.168.1.1,10, 
s1555098,IBM,"Server Room C",2018-11-18,02:00:03,516.514,404.671,819027,601233,,192.168.1.1,2, 
x6883582,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-05-19,04:50:02,26.444,12.506,88871436,84360552,,192.168.1.1,4,
```

For example, for data line #1 and #2:

```
x6883101,HP,"Server Room A",2019-07-14,04:50:02,26.444,11.521,49193480,41904833,,192.168.1.1,4,Sunday
s3398577,Dell,"Server Room B",2019-09-21,10:50:02,56.574,37.608,48955461,45858381,,192.168.1.1,10,Saturday
```

I've tried various SED and AWK with nothing.  I've tried the DATE command, but it doesn't seem to like input. I've been able to isolate the actual date from

> grep -w -o "20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*"

but nothing that I see is able to convert it and append the DOW at the end of the lines.

What am I missing that makes appending the Day of the Week to the end of each of the lines of data??  Also, I need to be able to do this from a CRONTAB job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `awk`, you could do:

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -F, -v OFS=, -v date_field=4 '
  (t = mktime(gensub("-", " ", "g", $date_field) " 0 0 0")) > 0 {
    $NF = strftime("%A", t)};1' your-file
```

- `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`: enables the in-place editing mode of gawk, whereby the output is written into a new file destined to be the replacement of the input file. **Do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`
- `-F,` and `-v OFS=,` set the input and output field separators
- `mktime()` is a GNU awk extension that parses a string in the `year month day hour minute second` format and returns the corresponding Unix epoch time. Here, we use `gensub()` (another gawk extension) to replace the `-` with spaces in the 4th field (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so as to pass a `YYYY MM DD 0 0 0` time to `mktime()`.
- `(t = mktime(...)) > 0 {...}` and `1` are two `condition {action}` pairs which are run on every input record (here *lines*).

  - For the first one, the *condition* checks if the value returned by `mktime()` (assigned to `t`) is greater than 0 (`mktime()` returns `-1` if it cannot parse the date specification), in which case the *action* is run. `strftime()` (another gawk extension) like its C equivalent is used to format a time (here the unix epoch time stored in `t` with format `%A`: the localised week day name). We assign the result to the `NF`th field (`$NF`), `NF` being the special variable that contains the number of fields in the current record and `$` being an operator to retrieve fields contents (or the full record with `$ 0`).
  - the second one (`1`) is missing the *action* part which defaults to `{print}` (prints the current record), and the *condition* (`1`) is always true. That's the idiomatic short way to unconditionally print the current record, it you wanted to be more verbose, you could do:

    ```
        gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk \
             -v FS=, \
             -v OFS=, \
             -v date_field=4 \
             -v current_record=0 \
             -v always=1 '
          {
            date_for_mktime = gensub("-", " ", "g", $date_field) " 0 0 0"
            unix_time = mktime(date_for_mktime)
          } 
          unix_time > 0 {
            $NF = strftime("%A", unix_time)
          }
          always {print $current_record}' your-file
    ```

If you want the week day names to always be in English regardless of the locale of the user, you can fix the locale to `C` (`LC_ALL=C gawk...`).

Comment: I stand corrected, it is possible in a one-liner after all. Perhaps you could add an explanation how it works, i.e. that you generated a "full" date-time specification that can be fed to `awk`s internal `strftime` function (a point I struggled with, leading to my more lengthy answer).

Comment: @AdminBee, see edit

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Thank you so much!  This helped immensely and I learned something! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not possible using a "one-liner" *(Edit: it turnd out to be possible, [after all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/550903/377345))*, but you can do this using a shell script. Core is the use of the `date` utility to retrieve the weekday from the date you have already extracted.

To do this, look at the output of

```
user@host $ date +%A -d 2019-07-14
Sunday
```

Using this, you can write a script which reads the input file line-wise, extracts the week day for each line except the header, and writes the header unchanged and all other lines with weekday appended to a different file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if input and output filenames were specified
if [[ "$#" != "2" ]]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <input filename> <output filename>"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -e "$1" ]]
then
    echo "Error, $1 doesn't exist!"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ "$1" == "$2" ]]
then
    echo "Error, input and output filenames must not be equal!"#
    exit 1
fi



# Perform the actual transformation
while read input
do
    if [[ -n "$(grep "^Server" <<< $input)" ]]
    then
    echo "$input" > $2
    else
    date=$(awk '{match($0,",(20[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2})",a); print a[1]}' <<< $input)
    wday=$(date +%A -d $date)
    echo "$input$wday" >> $2
    fi
done < $1
```

### To explain

The first part are sanity checks on the input, they could also be peformed otherwise.

The second part is the actual loop over the lines of your input file.

- First, we check if the current line is the "header" by using `grep` to determine if it starts with the string "Server". If the result of `grep` is a non-empty string, write it to the output file "as is".
- Then, use `awk` to find the pattern "20YY-MM-DD", enclosed by commas, and extract the actual value into the internal array `a` which is assigned to the bash variable `$date`.
- This variable is now used in the call to `date` as specified above to return the day of week.
- The input line, with appended weekday, is then written to the output file.

Answer (score 1):

With [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) (`mlr`):

```
mlr --csvlite put '
  $Hour = ""; $DOW = strftime(strptime($Datestamp,"%Y-%m-%d"),"%A")
' file.csv
```

Ex.

```
$ mlr --csvlite put '$Hour = ""; $DOW = strftime(strptime($Datestamp,"%Y-%m-%d"),"%A")' file.csv
Server ID,Make,"Server Room",Datestamp,Timestamp,Distance,Ping,Download,Upload,Payload,"Src IP Address",Hour,DOW
x6883101,HP,"Server Room A",2019-07-14,04:50:02,26.444,11.521,49193480,41904833,,192.168.1.1,,Sunday
s3398577,Dell,"Server Room B",2019-09-21,10:50:02,56.574,37.608,48955461,45858381,,192.168.1.1,,Saturday
x6883551,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-08-16,02:00:04,26.444,17.921,86551957,88775986,,192.168.1.1,,Friday
s1555023,HP,"Server Room C",2018-02-06,04:50:01,516.574,402.527,907658,608152,,192.168.1.1,,Tuesday
s3398023,HP,"Server Room B",2019-01-17,10:50:01,56.574,40.233,48484827,45620028,,192.168.1.1,,Thursday
s1555098,IBM,"Server Room C",2018-11-18,02:00:03,516.514,404.671,819027,601233,,192.168.1.1,,Sunday
x6883582,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-05-19,04:50:02,26.444,12.506,88871436,84360552,,192.168.1.1,,Sunday
```

Package `miller` is available from the Ubuntu 16.04 `universe` repository.

Answer (score 1):

my first reaction was the same as Stephane's.

Perl would work too:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F, -lape '
  if ($F[3] =~ /^[\d-]+$/) {
    $F[-1] = Time::Piece->strptime($F[3], "%Y-%m-%d")->strftime("%A");
    $_ = join ",", @F;
  }
' file
```

Comment: This also respects the LC_ALL setting.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %days  = ( 1 => "Monday", 2 => "Tuesday", 3 => "Wednesday", 4 => "Thursday", 5 => "Friday", 6 => "Saturday", 7 => "Sunday" ) andthen put get;  
             put $_, %days{.split(",")[3].Date.day-of-week.Str};'  file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %days  = ( 1 => "Monday", 2 => "Tuesday", 3 => "Wednesday", 4 => "Thursday", 5 => "Friday", 6 => "Saturday", 7 => "Sunday" );  
             $++ == 0 ?? .put !! put $_, %days{.split(",")[3].Date.day-of-week.Str};'  file
```

Above are answers coded in Raku, a programming language in the Perl-family. Both examples use the `-ne` autoprinting linewise flags.

In the first example a hash `%days` is declared in the `BEGIN` block. To print out the header line `put get` is used (for two-line headers use  `put (get xx 2)`. In the second example, Raku's ternary operator is used to print the header: `$++ == 0` ?? (True) `!!` (False). For two-line headers use `$++ < 2`.

Both examples print out the `$_` topic variable, followed by code to compute the day-of-week. This code, `.split(",")[3].Date.day-of-week.Str`, splits on comma, takes zero-index == 3 (4th column), reads it as a `Date` object, computes the numeric `day-of-week`, which is converted to a `Str` string. This numeric day-of-week is then looked up in the `%days{ … }` hash to give the alphabetic day.

Sample Input:

```
Server ID,Make,"Server Room",Datestamp,Timestamp,Distance,Ping,Download,Upload,Payload,"Src IP Address",Hour,DOW
x6883101,HP,"Server Room A",2019-07-14,04:50:02,26.444,11.521,49193480,41904833,,192.168.1.1,4, 
s3398577,Dell,"Server Room B",2019-09-21,10:50:02,56.574,37.608,48955461,45858381,,192.168.1.1,10, 
x6883551,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-08-16,02:00:04,26.444,17.921,86551957,88775986,,192.168.1.1,2, 
s1555023,HP,"Server Room C",2018-02-06,04:50:01,516.574,402.527,907658,608152,,192.168.1.1,4, 
s3398023,HP,"Server Room B",2019-01-17,10:50:01,56.574,40.233,48484827,45620028,,192.168.1.1,10, 
s1555098,IBM,"Server Room C",2018-11-18,02:00:03,516.514,404.671,819027,601233,,192.168.1.1,2, 
x6883582,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-05-19,04:50:02,26.444,12.506,88871436,84360552,,192.168.1.1,4,
```

Sample Output:

```
Server ID,Make,"Server Room",Datestamp,Timestamp,Distance,Ping,Download,Upload,Payload,"Src IP Address",Hour,DOW
x6883101,HP,"Server Room A",2019-07-14,04:50:02,26.444,11.521,49193480,41904833,,192.168.1.1,4, Sunday
s3398577,Dell,"Server Room B",2019-09-21,10:50:02,56.574,37.608,48955461,45858381,,192.168.1.1,10, Saturday
x6883551,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-08-16,02:00:04,26.444,17.921,86551957,88775986,,192.168.1.1,2, Friday
s1555023,HP,"Server Room C",2018-02-06,04:50:01,516.574,402.527,907658,608152,,192.168.1.1,4, Tuesday
s3398023,HP,"Server Room B",2019-01-17,10:50:01,56.574,40.233,48484827,45620028,,192.168.1.1,10, Thursday
s1555098,IBM,"Server Room C",2018-11-18,02:00:03,516.514,404.671,819027,601233,,192.168.1.1,2, Sunday
x6883582,Dell,"Server Room A",2019-05-19,04:50:02,26.444,12.506,88871436,84360552,,192.168.1.1,4,Sunday
```

https://raku.org